# How to find the correct relationships between my tables?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying out a new django social media project which has User, Status and Comment. The relationship between them is such that, User has a relationship to Status, User has relationship to Comment and there also exists a relationship between Status and comment.

So to achieve this I built four tables, i.e, User, Comment, Status and UCSModel. Where UCSModel is the table which has the foreign keys of the rest three tables. UCSModel is more like the relations table consisting of all ID's

So here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Comment(models.Model):

    comment = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

class Status(models.Model):

    status = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class USCRelation(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Being new to Django, I wanted to know if there is any better way of building relationships between tables. Especially when all the three tables are interrelated to each other like in my case above.

Comment: How the status and comment table are interrelated?

Comment: @bharat The status and comment are interrelated as I want to get all the comments for a particular status. It's more like a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below DB design, this would help you optimising your queries:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Status(models.Model):

    status = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class Comment(models.Model):

    comment = models.CharField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @bharatn thank you. I had kept the comment table separate because in future I thought of implementing likes and dislikes sort of option. So that was the reason why I had a separate UCSmodel here.

Comment: Please ask the question in such a way which depicts the full requirement. That would help us in giving the answer more appropriately and relevant. Thanks